# In Sequelize, how do you exclude the primary key column in an include join operation on MySQL database

Tags: sequelize.js

given the following query

```
model.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('price')), 'totalPrice'],
  ],
  include: {
    model: otherModel
    attributes: ['userId'],
    where: {
      userId: 1
    }
  }
  group: ['otherModel.userId']
});
```

where otherModel.id is the primary key on that table, it outputs a query that looks like

```
SELECT
  sum(`price`) AS`totalPrice`,
  `OtherModel`.`id` AS `OtherModel.id`,
  `OtherModel`.`userId` AS `OtherModel.userId`
  ...
```

which is giving me a `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column` error.  How can I make it so that `OtherModel.id AS OtherModel.id` does not get generated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "attributes" option as an object instead and provide "include" and "exclude" arrays to exclude a column:

```
model.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('price')), 'totalPrice']
  ],
  include: {
    model: otherModel,
    attributes: {
      include: ['userId'],
      exclude: ['id']
    },
    where: { userId: 1 }
  },
  group: ['OtherModel.userId']
});
```